# While monitor won't stop running (php)

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm using a while loop to output a "." whilst a server side script is running using exec. This works great apart form the fact that it never stops running, i.e. "........" would continue building to infinity!

Does anyone know a way to make this client side update once it's finished running:

```
$dbupdate = ($siteurl."/data_update.php");

$runupdate = exec("nohup curl ".$dbupdate." > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!");

while(exec("ps $runupdate"))
{ 
     echo(" . ");
       ob_flush(); flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `while()` will keep executing until the condition is `false/null/0`, and `exec()` returns void.
DOCS: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Something like this might help?

```
$runupdate = exec("nohup curl ".$dbupdate." > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!");
// Spitballing here...
$pid = true;
// Execute only while $op is strictly true, and not the PID that `echo $!` returns
while( $pid === true )
{ 
     exec("ps $runupdate", $pid);
     echo(" . ");
     ob_flush(); flush();
}
```

Check out the docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#88704

Comment: How should `$pid` ever change to a value different from `true`?